# Equals or less in if sentence doesn't work

Tags: c#, if-statement

So I've made a simple shop to buy an upgrade for a game I'm making. When I have the right or more amount of cookies I can buy the upgrade and it does show up the message box, but if I have less it doesn't do anything. No message box or anything.

```
public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //2CookiesPerClick
    {
        for (MessageBox.Show("Checking..."); cookies > 9;n++)
        {
            if (cookies > 9)
            {
                panel1.Hide();
                cookies -= 10;
                MessageBox.Show("You bought 2 Cookies per Click!");
            }
            if (cookies < 9)
            {
                button1.Show();
                label2.Show();
                MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough cookies to buy this upgrade!");
            }

        }

    }
```

EDIT:
Updated it and it works thanks to Rob and Amadeusz Wieczorek!
Updated code:

```
public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)//2CookiesPerClick
    {
            if (cookies >= 10)
            {
                n++;
                panel1.Hide();
                cookies -= 10;
                MessageBox.Show("You bought 2 Cookies per Click!");
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Show();
                label2.Show();
                MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough cookies to buy this upgrade!");
            }

    }
```

Comment: And your question !?

Comment: Is that `for` loop an oops?

Comment: According to the mangled `for` loop, you'll never enter it if you have less than 9 cookies.

Comment: Your `for` loop runs while `cookies > 9`, so unless `cookies` is updated in a separate thread the interior of the loop will never have a `cookies` value less than 9.

Comment: even if you could enter that for loop, what happens if `cookies` is exactly 9?

Comment: I didn't even know one could do that with a for loop, and I wish I could unsee what I have seen.

Comment: @DrewKennedy You can do more than that.  A `for (initializer; condition; iterator)` loop can have multiple comma separated initializers and iterators that can be almost anything.  Only the condition requires one statement that returns a `bool`.

Comment: @juharr The initializers have to all be of the same type though, AFAIK. I never considered putting a `cw` as an initializer, and I probably will never find a reason to.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Nope, the initializers can be any statement, type doesn't come into play.  Check out some of the examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

Comment: @juharr Well paint me green and call me Gumby.Thanks for the documentation. Learning new stuff all the time, even if it's about the basics, is what makes programming so much fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- What's `n`? I replaced it with `attempt`.

  - I didn't quite understand the logic in the for loop so I might have changed your desired behavior
- I moved the message box code into the loop

  - It's a good practice not to do logic in the for loop's condition.
- I changed the `if`, `if` into `if`, `else`. This has 2 benefits:

  - You no longer need to check second condition (cookies < 9)
  - You had an error in checking for the second condition - what happens when cookies == 9?
  - You are absolutely sure that only one branch will execute

The big takeaway is to make the code simpler, do one thing at a time, and and don't repeat yourself :) Hopefully this will cut down your number of bugs.

Here is the updated code:

```
    MessageBox.Show("Checking...");
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 10; attempt++)
    {
        cookies++;
        if (cookies >= 10)
        {
            panel1.Hide();
            cookies -= 10;
            MessageBox.Show("You bought 2 Cookies per Click!");
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Show();
            label2.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough cookies to buy this upgrade!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a feeling the for-loop isn't needed at all. Judging by the message 'per click', and the fact that it's in a click handler, it appears to me that only the `if` statements are required

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is weird:

```
for (MessageBox.Show("Checking..."); cookies > 9;n++)
```

This loop is not entered when `cookies <= 9`. So your `if` statement is never reached.

Comment: there's more than that weird about the for loop

Comment: I would imagine that removing the `for-loop` entirely would solve the problem.

Comment: @user1666620 yes, but that is the weird part explaining the behaviour OP is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work, because the loop condition says "loop only when the number of cookies is greater than nine". If the number is less than nine or equal to nine the loop will never be executed!

And also, it is unclear to me why you are using a loop at all. Shouldn't this code just be executed once each time the button is clicked?

---

The idiomatic way of using a for loop is

```
const int N = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    ...
}
```

If there is no limit

```
for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
    ...
}
```

It is technically possible to call the message box in for-part, but is very very very very uncommon! This place is reserved for the declaration and initialization of loop variables. Better: call the message box before the loop:

```
MessageBox.Show("Checking...");
for (int cookies = 0; true; cookies++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop will keep executing the code within until a condition is not met (and, indeed, can never execute at all). Since your code is in a click event, and your message specifically mentions 'per click', it appears to me the `for` loop is irrelevant.

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //2CookiesPerClick
{
   MessageBox.Show("Checking...")

   if (cookies > 9)
   {
       panel1.Hide();
       cookies -= 10;
       MessageBox.Show("You bought 2 Cookies per Click!");
   }
   if (cookies <= 9)
   {
       button1.Show();
       label2.Show();
       MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough cookies to buy this upgrade!");
   }
}
```

Since this looks like a homework question, I'd advise you to compare the above with your current code, to figure out *why* your code didn't work. Feel free to leave a comment if you're still confused

Comment: Already got it! Thank you! You're awesome. I'm a newbie so excuse my idiocy